# how to automatically color the lines for each different word, to make it easier to see the difference

Tags: excel

I have so many product names, and it's hard for me to see the difference in each price in a product.
how can i automatically color the row in each different word, so i can easily see the difference in each product

an example as in the image below
[image]

Comment: I would use conditional formatting, then you can use shades of red for a product family as well for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conditional Formatting By Group

Here's how you can conditionally format by groups

• In cell **G1** (same row as the header) enter zero,

• In cell **G2** enter the below formula,

```
=IF(A2=A1,G1,G1+1)
```

• Select the data range, as shown in image below **`A2:F17`**,

• Press ALT `H` + `L` + `N` to show the **New Formatting Rule** dialog box

• Now enter a new rule formula — use a formula to determine which cells to format — with the below formula

```
=AND(LEN($A2)>0,MOD($G2,2)=1)
```

• Click the **Format** button --> **Fill Tab** --> Choose desired color --> Press Ok.

**Side Note:** Hide the column (**column G**) where you have the formula.

[image: Conditional Formatting By Group]

Comment: thanks a lot, I've tried it and it works very well, once again thanks u so much, hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: @Nata_The_Coco did you delete your last comment? Glad it worked for you, and thank you for sharing the feedback!

Comment: sorry my comment disappeared i didn't notice that. maybe because that time i edited my comment to add emoji

Comment: Alright, noted!